# Pushing in git versus uploading in github

Tags: git, github

I've recently started learning version control using git. I'm using github as the remote repository.
My question is: 
What is the difference between pushing files using git to github and directly uploading files to our github repository?
If there is no difference, why do we need git when github being the most popular site for doing version control is available?

*** By directly uploading to github, I mean that when you create a repository, the interface in github provides a button to upload files.

Comment: Explain what you mean by the second method `directly uploading files` to GitHub.

Comment: Pushing files using git IS a direct upload to github... you'll have to elaborate a bit.

Comment: Github doesn't "do version control". Git does. Github is the most popular place to put git repos.

Answer (score 0):

At its core, Github is a place to host a git repository so that others can copy it. It also provides a bunch of fancy webpage surrounding the git repository to provide other services that a traditional git repository does not do by default: serve wiki pages, do issue tracking, manage pull requests (to name a few).

Uploading to Github is synonymous to running `git add` with a bunch of files, followed by a `git commit` and `git push`.

> If there is no difference, why do we need git when github being the most popular site for doing version control is available?

Without git, there is no Github . Github is not Dropbox. Github is a `git remote` that provides services in addition to what is already offered by git.